# jhipster upgrade again fail on Windows 10

Tags: jhipster

Today I use "jhipster upgrade" to my application (in a new branch, and the jhipster version is v5.8.2, npm and yarn also latest version), and get a lot of conflict, then I use two below git commands to quit the merge conflict:

```
git checkout -- .
git merge abort
```

Then I delete the branch and create it again, when I run "jhipster upgrade" again, the upgrade progress go on, looks like a lot of things upgraded as before, but when I check with "git status", nothing changed.

I checked the upgrade screen and found a fatal message as:

```
....
Merging changes back to upgrade01...
     info git merge -q jhipster_upgrade
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
....
```

Anyone konw what prevent the upgrade progress? How can I upgrade again?

Comment: Have you tried running it with `--debug`?

Comment: tried with "jhipster upgrade --debug", still cannot upgrade

Comment: The objective of using --debug was not to make it pass, it was to collect information on why it fails.

Comment: the screenoutput is the same as before